# Random forest (rfsrc) in R not reproducible despite setting seed

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am not able to reproduce my Random Forest rfsrc results despite setting a seed. Each time I run the code below I see a different ordering to variables listed by order of importance.  Here is what I've tried:

```
set.seed(415)
fit1sjl <- rfsrc(Social_Jetlag_Comp ~ ., data=df, importance="permute", 
    ntree=2000)
```

I've also tried

```
fit1sjl <- rfsrc(Social_Jetlag_Comp ~ ., data=df, importance="permute", 
    ntree=2000, seed=415)
```

What am I doing incorrectly? If it helps the overall variance explained (OOB estimate) is very low.

Comment: what about when setting the `seed = -415L` inside `rfsrc`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing it to a negative integer but I'm still running into the same issue.  The OOB R squared is the same across runs but the ordering of variable importance changes significantly with each run.  As I'm mainly interested in the ordering of variable importance this is clearly not ideal

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForestSRC/versions/3.0.1/topics/randomForestSRC-package check the reproducibility part - the authors specify variable importance is not subject to seed.

Comment: @missuse I kindly suggest you post this as an answer (quoting the part).

Comment: Ah, yes!  Thank you @missuse, I had missed this. From https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForestSRC/versions/3.0.1/topics/randomForestSRC-package  "With respect to reproducibility, a model is defined by a seed, the topology of the trees in the forest, and terminal node membership of the training data. This allows the user to restore a model and, in particular, its terminal node statistics. On the other hand, VIMP and many other statistics are dependent on additional randomization, which we do not consider part of the model. These statistics are susceptible to Monte Carlo effects."

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [randomForestSRC](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForestSRC/versions/3.0.1/topics/randomForestSRC-package)

it is written that:

> With respect to reproducibility, a model is defined by a seed, the
> topology of the trees in the forest, and terminal node membership of
> the training data. This allows the user to restore a model and, in
> particular, its terminal node statistics. On the other hand, VIMP and
> many other statistics are dependent on additional randomization, which
> we do not consider part of the model. These statistics are susceptible
> to Monte Carlo effects.

Therefore variable importance (VIMP) is not implemented in the package to be reproducible.